# xpath: Limit the scope of ancestor to count elements which have specific parent within the specific nodes

Tags: xpath

I try to select all elements which has attribute name `itemprop` and which has any level parent with attribute `itemtype = http://schema.org/Product` except elements  located in nodes with any other attribute `//*[@itemtype not(@itemprop)]`.

Example:

```
<div itemtype = "http://schema.org/Product" >
  <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" >
    <div itemprop = "name" > A </div>
    <div itemprop = "price" > B </div>
    <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/ListItem" >
      <div itemprop = "description"> C </div>
    </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemtype = "http://schema.org/Offer" >
      <div itemprop = "price"> D </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop = "name" > E </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div itemprop = "price" > F </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need only `D`, `E` and `F` elements but not `A`, `B`, `C`. I tried something like this:

```
//*[@itemprop and count(ancestor::*[@itemtype='http://schema.org/Product'])=count(ancestor::*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)])]
```

It works well, however, if there are more `itemtype`s and `itemprop`s as their ancestor, the case seems complicated.
Example:

```
<div itemtype = ""http://schema.org/WebPage" >
 //a lot of itemtypes and itemprops between them as Product nodes' ancestor//
  <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/Product" >
    <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" >
      <div itemprop = "name" > A </div>
      <div itemprop = "price" > B </div>
      <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/ListItem" >
        <div itemprop = "description"> C </div>
      </div>
     <div itemprop="offers" itemtype = "http://schema.org/Offer" >
        <div itemprop = "price"> D </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop = "name" > E </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div itemprop = "price" > F </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, my questions is that, is there any way to limit the scope of ancestor?

```
<div itemtype = ""http://schema.org/WebPage" >
a lot of itemtypes and itemprops between them as Product nodes' ancestor
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Calculate count of ancestor from here
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/Product" >
    <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" >
      <div itemprop = "name" > A </div>
      <div itemprop = "price" > B </div>
      <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/ListItem" >
        <div itemprop = "description"> C </div>
      </div>
     <div itemprop="offers" itemtype = "http://schema.org/Offer" >
        <div itemprop = "price"> D </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop = "name" > E </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div itemprop = "price" > F </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
To here
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
........
</div>
```

To summarise, after I select node `//*[contains(@itemtype, 'schema.org/Product') and not(@itemprop)]`, I would like to count its ancestor within the nodes.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Without the limit the scope of ancestor, this code work:

```
//*[@itemprop and count(ancestor::*[contains(@itemtype, 'schema.org/Product') and not(@itemprop)])+count(//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop) and descendant::*[contains(@itemtype, 'schema.org/Product') and not(@itemprop)]])=count(ancestor::*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)])]
```

Is this the best?
Many thank to all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to select the leaf of your tree: the elements with `itemprop` attribute. Also you want only those having their first ancestor with only `itemtype` attribute and `"http://schema.org/Product"` attribute value.

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//*[@itemprop][not(@itemtype)]
   [ancestor::*[@itemtype][not(@itemprop)][1]
               [@itemtype='http://schema.org/Product']
   ]
```

With this proper wellformed input *(do note the closed BreadcrumbList)*:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">//a lot of itemtypes and itemprops between them as Product nodes' ancestor//
  <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
      <div itemprop="name">A</div>
      <div itemprop="price">B</div>
      <div itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <div itemprop="description">C</div>
      </div>
</div>
      <div itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div itemprop="price">D</div>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="name">E</div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div itemprop="price">F</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It selects:

```
<div itemprop="price">D</div>

<div itemprop="name">E</div>

<div itemprop="price">F</div>
```

Check [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/434acb4abd03054e38b0a2f3b525f7cc)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It works well. Could you let me know the second line?  [ancestor::*[@itemtype][not(@itemprop)][1][@itemtype='http://schema.org/Product']] ? Does it mean node's first ancestor @itemtype and not (itemprop) should be @itemtype='http://schema.org/Product' ? Many many thanks :)

Comment: Yes. Positional predicate `[1]` expanded to `[position()=1]` works in the direction of the axis of the location step. For `ancestor` it means the first in hierarchy upward direction.